# How do I get the text body lower but not make it a footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xcode, web

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="NWC.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--Font Import Links-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!---JS File Imports-->
    <script src="NWC.js">
    </script>
    <!--HTML Code Starts Below-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo_container">
                <h1>N W C</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--Cover Section-->
    <section>
        <div class="coverpic">
            <img src="file:///C:/Users/jakes/Desktop/NWC/nwcgfrey.png" alt="NWC LOGO" width="60%" height="40%">
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--About Section-->
    <section>
        <div class="about-section">
            <h1>About NWC</h1>
            <p>New World Coding is a startup teaching kids to program. Coding is an essential skill to learn because it is our future. All of our technology today whether it's using a computer to making a pot of coffee is run by the code engineers write. Here at NWC, we have group lessons for you and a friend, or 1:1 lessons! For more information about NWC, our lessons, or any other questions, please fill click the button below.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/jakes/nwcWebsitecity.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

.header {
    display: block;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    background-size: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;    
}
/*
.inner_header {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
*/
.logo_container {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
}

.logo_container h1{
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 10px;
    
}


.coverpic {
    bottom: 750px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
}



.about-section {
    background-image:       
    url(file:///C:/Users/jakes/nwcWebsitecity.png);
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(180);
  }
```

[What site looks like now, I just want to move the body section lower[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghQoE.png)

Basically, I want the text body to move down lower so that you don't see it when you first load into the site, I want the .coverpic to be centered when you first load into the site and when you start scrolling you see the about section.

Comment: You can use `height: 100vh;` for the first section, that way it will be as high as the window content.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your text (p tag):

```
<p class= "sample">
```

and then adjust the margin in your CSS:

```
.sample {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

adjust the margin-top accordingly for how low you want the text to go.

edit: change the "color" in your about-section to black for example. Basically you have white on white right now.

You'll also notice that I added margin-top: 50px on both about-section and sample classes. The first margin-top brings the title down and the second brings the text down.

```
    .about-section {
    background-image:       
    url(file:///C:/Users/jakes/nwcWebsitecity.png);
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(180);
    margin-top: 50px;
  }



 .sample {
      margin-top: 50px;
    };
```

Comment: Now the text doesn't appear at all

Comment: Take a look at my edits in my original comment. Now you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

U can use margine-top in css.
which text u want to lower just write in css margine-top: and how px u want.
Like example

```
    h1 {
margine-top: 50%;}
```

to be in the middle screen or just lower or more high % to make it in the right position